# How do I open an IE window as a different user in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

This works:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

And this appears to work:

```
$username = "domain\user"
$password = "password"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
```

But when I run this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -Credential $cred
```

I get this:
[image: ISE Error]

I have also tried this, with the same outcome:

```
$iePath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath $iePath -Credential $cred
```

Why would I get a directory error when I am providing the full path to `iexplore.exe`?

Comment: Your example command works for me. Use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) while you run it and see what is throwing the directory name error. My guess is it will be something in the user's profile folder, rather than the IE path.

Comment: Does your remote user "domain\user" have the rights to access "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" on the local PC?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself using

- `Start-Process -FilePath "notepad"`
- `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"`

Both work as-is.

If I add `-Credentials` *(my own current credentials)* it fails with the errormessage `The directory name is invalid`.

Neither procmon nor windbg gave me any clues *(I'm convinced they are there using windbg but I couldn't find it)*

Adding `-WorkingDirectory` though solved it

```
Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Credential $cred -WorkingDirectory "c:\windows\system32"
```

**Edit**

Following the WorkingDirectory train of thought, I noticed my current working directory being a mapped network drive (F:). Switching my current working directory to a local drive also "solved" the issue.

```
PS F:\>> Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Credential $cred
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Credential $cred
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
PS F:\>> c:
PS C:\>> Start-Process -FilePath "notepad" -Credential $cred
PS C:\>>
```